# Laravel 5 : Strange error, simple OR logic in middleware?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I just stumble upon on strange error simple OR logic in middleware.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    //can create user, 1 Super Administrator, 2 Administrator
    //dd(Auth::user()->role_id); //print 2

    if((Auth::user()->role_id != "1") || (Auth::user()->role_id != "2")){
        return Auth::user()->role_id . " is not equal with 1 or 2, logic true";
    }else{
        return Auth::user()->role_id . " is equal with 1 or 2, logic false";
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

When i visit protected route, I always get `2 is not equal with 1 or 2, logic true`, in this case `Auth::user()->role_id` is `2`.

So is there anything wrong with my code ? but if i just run one statement, the logic is run very well, so I think the problem come, when I use more than one statement.

Actually i just want to check if logged in user `role_id` is `1` or `2` if so, then do next request, else return to somewhere with error message. But stumble upon on this weird error.

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Comment: You will always enter the if statement.

Comment: Hi @Rizier123 can you please give me some example ? :D Thanks.

Comment: With your OR operator, only 1 side has to be true to enter the if statement. Now: `x != 1` can only be false when it is equals 1. Same for `x != 2`. So your variable would need to be 1 and 2 at the same time to NOT enter the if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Code:

```
if ($a != 1 || $a != 2) {
    echo 'x';
} else {
    echo 'y';
}
```

#### Scenarios:

```
|----|--------|
| $a | result |
|----|--------|
|  0 |   x    |
|  1 |   x    | // <- result is x because $a is not 2
|  2 |   x    | // <- result is x because $a is not 1
|  3 |   x    |
|----|--------|
```

**Because** `$a` is always either not 1 or not 2.

## Code:

```
if ($a != 1 && $a != 2) {
    echo 'x';
} else {
    echo 'y';
}
```

#### Scenarios:

```
|----|--------|
| $a | result |
|----|--------|
|  0 |   x    |
|  1 |   y    |
|  2 |   y    |
|  3 |   x    |
|----|--------|
```

Comment: ah.. human error, i should use AND instead of OR because i need two statement to be true, while OR only need one statement to be true.

Thanks in advace Hkan.

Comment: @DarkCyber no problem. Have a nice day.